# Shall I use asyncio.create_task() before calling asyncio.gather()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I was wondering if there is any benefit of directly calling `asyncio.gather(*coros)` rather than starting the tasks with `asyncio.create_task()` and then calling `asyncio.gather(*tasks)`.

So I did this test (please tell me if you notice any bias):

```
import timeit

test1 = """
async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    
async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(sleep()) for s in range(1000)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
"""

test2 = """
async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():
    tasks = [sleep() for s in range(1000)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
"""

print("TEST 1:", timeit.repeat(stmt=test1, setup="import asyncio", repeat=5, number=10000))
print("TEST 2:", timeit.repeat(stmt=test2, setup="import asyncio", repeat=5, number=10000))
```

Here's the result:

```
TEST 1: [123.09070299999999, 118.88883120000001, 120.92030820000002, 121.22180739999999, 116.49616249999997]
TEST 2: [109.63426249999998, 108.96809150000001, 110.66497140000001, 105.34163260000003, 105.78473080000003]
```

It seems like there is no overhead when `gather()` has to create the tasks - it's even faster (although [ensure_future()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4bb332cfd1f9740b1e31d2d8b8bf1bedca3439ff/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L614) is called internally, if I understand well).

Any thoughts on this? Shall I follow the pattern used for test 2 rather than the one used for test 1? The Zen does not help much there, but as it outlines, "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it".

Comment: Do you need to interact with the task objects If not, there's no need to call `create_task`.

Comment: There is no reason to call `create_task` yourself because that's literally the first thing `gather()` does for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use asyncio.create\_task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107909/when-should-i-use-asyncio-create-task)