# When should I use asyncio.create_task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, task, python-asyncio, coroutine

I am using Python 3.10 and I am a bit confused about `asyncio.create_task`.

In the following example code, the functions are executed in coroutines whether or not I use `asyncio.create_task`. It seems that there is no difference.

How can I determine when to use `asyncio.create_task` and what are the advantages of using `asyncio.create_task` compared to without it?

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import sleep

async def process(index: int):
    await sleep(1)
    print('ok:', index)

async def main1():
    tasks = []
    for item in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(process(item)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def main2():
    tasks = []
    for item in range(10):
        tasks.append(process(item)) # Without asyncio.create_task
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main1())
asyncio.run(main2())
```

Comment: `create_task` submits the coroutine to run "in the background", i.e. concurrently with the current task and all other tasks, switching between them at await points. It returns an awaitable handle called a "task" which you can also use to cancel the execution of the coroutine.

Comment: You're not seeing a difference here because `asyncio.gather` already wraps coroutines in tasks, so creating the tasks yourself doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user2357112 So add `asyncio.create_task` is unnecessary when I use `asyncio.gather`?

Comment: [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather): ... "If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled as a Task." ... (RTFM)

Comment: @user2357112 That is not entirely correct. Creating the tasks _does_ change something, as soon as an additional context switch is introduced _after_ creation but _before_ the `gather` call. In this given example, there is indeed no difference, but in general that difference can be huge. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TL;DR

It makes sense to use `create_task`, if you want to schedule the execution of that coroutine **immediately**, but not necessarily wait for it to **finish**, instead moving on to something else first.

### Explanation

As has been pointed out in the comments already, [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) itself wraps the provided awaitables in tasks, which is why it is essentially redundant to call [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) on them beforehand in your simple example.

From the `gather` docs:

> If any awaitable [...] is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled as a Task.

---

That being said, the two examples you constructed are **not equivalent**!

When you call `create_task`, the Task is **immediately** scheduled for execution on the even loop. This means, if a context switch takes place after you called `create_task` for all your coroutines (as in your first example), any number of them *may* immediately start executing, **without** you having to `await` them explicitly.

From the `create_task` docs: (my emphasis)

> Wrap the [...] coroutine into a `Task` and **schedule its execution**.

By contrast, when you simply create the **coroutines** (as in your second example), they will **not begin execution** by themselves, unless you *somehow* schedule their execution (e.g. by simply `await`ing them).

You can see this in action, if you add any `await` (e.g. `asyncio.sleep`) between creation and the `gather` call and a few helpful `print` statements:

```py
from asyncio import create_task, gather, sleep, run


async def process(index: int):
    await sleep(.5)
    print('ok:', index)


async def create_tasks_then_gather():
    tasks = [create_task(process(item)) for item in range(5)]
    print("tasks scheduled")
    await sleep(2)  # <-- because of this `await` the tasks may begin to execute
    print("now gathering tasks")
    await gather(*tasks)
    print("gathered tasks")


async def create_coroutines_then_gather():
    coroutines = [process(item) for item in range(5)]
    print("coroutines created")
    await sleep(2)  # <-- despite this, the coroutines will not begin execution
    print("now gathering coroutines")
    await gather(*coroutines)
    print("gathered coroutines")


run(create_tasks_then_gather())
run(create_coroutines_then_gather())
```

Output:

```
tasks scheduled
ok: 0
ok: 1
ok: 2
ok: 3
ok: 4
now gathering tasks
gathered tasks
```

```
coroutines created
now gathering coroutines
ok: 0
ok: 1
ok: 2
ok: 3
ok: 4
gathered coroutines
```

As you can see, in `create_tasks_then_gather` the `process` body was executed *before* the `gather` call, whereas in `create_coroutines_then_gather` it was executed only *after*.

Therefore, whether or not using `create_task` is useful depends on the situation. If you only care about the coroutines being executed concurrently **and** awaited at that particular point in your code, there is no use in calling `create_task`. If you want to schedule them, but then move on to something else, while they may or may not do their thing in the background, it makes sense to use `create_task`.

One important thing to remember however is that you can *only ever* be sure that the tasks you scheduled actually execute completely, if you *at some point* `await` them. This is why you still *should* `await gather` them (or equivalent) to actually wait for them to finish eventually.