# What Actually Triggers the Asyncio Tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-asyncio

Trying to understand python `asyncio` coming from some background on multithreading with `concurrent.futures`. Here is the sample script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8
"""Sample script to test asyncio functionality."""

import asyncio
import logging
from time import sleep  # noqa
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

async def wait(i: int) -> None:
    """The main function to run asynchronously"""
    logging.info(msg=f'Entering wait {i}')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    logging.info(msg=f'Leaving wait {i}')  # This does not show because all pending tasks are SIGKILLed?

async def main() -> None:
    """The main."""
    [asyncio.create_task(
        coro=wait(i)) for i in range(10)]
    logging.info(msg='Created tasks, waiting before await.')
    sleep(5)  # This is meant to verify the tasks do not start by the create_task call.
    # What changes after the sleep command, i.e. here?
    # If the tasks did not start before the sleep, why would they start after the sleep?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main=main())
```

The technology stack, if relevant, is python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04. Here is my terminal output.

```
2023-05-03 12:30:45,297 | INFO: Created tasks, waiting before await.
2023-05-03 12:30:50,302 | INFO: Entering wait 0
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 1
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 2
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 3
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 4
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 5
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 6
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 7
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 8
2023-05-03 12:30:50,304 | INFO: Entering wait 9
```

So two related questions based on this snippet.

1. What exactly is triggering the `wait` async task here (which just logs two lines at the console upon entry and exit)? Clearly, creating the tasks is not really making them run, as I am waiting for long enough after creating them in main. Even the timestamps show they are run *after* the blocking sleep in main.
   Yet, just as the main function seems to finish its sleep, and exit, the tasks seem to be triggered. Should not the main thread just exit at this point?
2. The exit log is never printed (commented in the code). Does it mean the subprocess are just started after the main thread exits, and then immediately killed?

Comment: For Q1 it's `asyncio.create_task()` which schedules the `Awaitable` for execution after current synchronous code hits checkpoint - I'll test more about Q2 and question in code comments when I get home. Mind making numbered list of questions would ya? ;)

Comment: @jupiterbjy, thanks for getting back. Numbered the questions, but what exactly is a _checkpoint_? An ```await``` call? So I assume a task queue where tasks go in for execution, and as soon as the running task hits a _checkpoint_, it is taken out of the queue and placed at the back, and the next in queue starts running? Is that a reasonable mental model of what's happening?

Comment: There are no subprocesses or signals here. Behind asyncio calls is the event loop. The main() or any async call is not a simple call. asyncio.run() schedules execution on the event loop. When main() spawns tasks this event loop will pick them up eventually. This happens in asyncio.run() call. But the call itself waits for main() to finish, not child tasks. That's why it exits and doesn't wait for those other tasks. Note that there are two separate queues: one for tasks to start, one for awaiting tasks.

Comment: Why are you using a synchronous sleep instead of `asyncio.sleep`? You're freezing the event loop there.

Comment: @user2357112 I am doing that to check whether the ```create_task``` call is merely initialising the tasks, or setting them on a _running_ state . Thought the blocking sleep would give the interpreter enough _time_ to initalise and set them to running state if it wants to, before ```main``` exits. Turns out the interpreter sets the tasks as _running_ only after main exits.

Comment: @Della: It can't use that time to initialize the tasks, because it's busy sleeping!

Comment: asyncio is *cooperative, single-threaded, coroutine-based* concurrency. It is not a wrapper around threads or processes. If you want those, use `threading` or `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use asyncio.create\_task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107909/when-should-i-use-asyncio-create-task)

Comment: This is year late but just found enormous error on my answer, updated Q2 part since step 3. previously I for some reason wrote *"Other Tasks are ran after blocking"* which is completely wrong as you literally can see *"End of main!"* is shown *BEFORE* the *"Taks n started!"*. Since `main()` task wasn't done or met checkpoint, there was no chance for other tasks to be ever started until end of `main()` task. Sorry for misinformation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Q1:

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task):

> ***asyncio.create_task(coro, *, name=None, context=None)***
>
> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and **schedule** its execution. Return the Task object.
> ...
> The **task is executed in the loop returned by get_running_loop()**, RuntimeError is raised if there is no running loop in current thread.

And this scheduled task execution happens in so-called
*Checkpoints* - to quote from another great async library, [trio's docs](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#checkpoints):

> A checkpoint is two things:
>
> 1. A point where Trio checks for cancellation.
> 2. A point where Trio scheduler checks if it's good time to switch to another task.

Which is (most of time) what `await` keyword is.

(This need additional explanations to fully understand - it's after Q2)

---

### Q2:

To illustrate what happened in sequence after `asyncio.create_task(~~)`:

1. Tasks(Task is *not a subprocess*, but more roughly like coroutine - a suspendable function.) were just created and queued for execution.
2. But after `asyncio.create_task(~~)` call you called *Synchronous IO Operation* `time.sleep(5)` and suspended(blocked) *Main Thread* for 5 seconds. Therefore, nothing happened - no tasks actually even started.
3. After `time.sleep(5)` unblocks, `main()` task can now continue it's execution.
4. But there's no more `await` keyword in `main()` that would allow scheduler to switch to previously scheduled tasks. Therefore, after all *Synchronous codes* in `main()`, `main()` finishes without giving back control to scheduler, non of created tasks ran yet.
5. Since current task (for this case `main()` task) finished, now scheduler run the next pending task that was scheduled long ago, this is the time when that very first *"INFO: Entering wait 0"* is called.
6. Each scheduled tasks ran and hit checkpoint `await asyncio.sleep(5)`, yield control back to scheduler and awaiting for re-schedule *AFTER* `(current time + 5)`. Then scheduler runs next pending tasks, repeats this process. (*Entering wait 1, 2, ...*)
7. All tasks ran and is pending to be re-scheduled, but since main task `main()` that we gave to `asyncio.run` already exited, scheduler decides to cancel all remaining tasks.
8. Now nothing is pending *asyncio*'s loop stops and exit gracefully.

This can be demonstrated with a bit more logging/printing:

```py
"""Sample script to test asyncio functionality."""

import asyncio
import time


async def wait(i: int) -> None:
    print(f"Task {i} started!")

    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
    except (asyncio.CancelledError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        print(f"Task {i} canceled!")
        raise

    print(f"Task {i} done!")


async def main() -> None:
    """The main."""
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(wait(i)) for i in range(10)]

    print("Blocking main thread for 5 sec!")
    time.sleep(5)

    print("End of main!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main=main())
    print("asyncio loop stopped!")
```

Outputs:

```
Blocking main thread for 5 sec!
End of main!
Task 0 started!
Task 1 started!
Task 2 started!
Task 3 started!
Task 4 started!
Task 5 started!
Task 6 started!
Task 7 started!
Task 8 started!
Task 9 started!
Task 9 canceled!
Task 4 canceled!
Task 0 canceled!
Task 1 canceled!
Task 7 canceled!
Task 2 canceled!
Task 5 canceled!
Task 8 canceled!
Task 3 canceled!
Task 6 canceled!
asyncio loop stopped!
```

Try following above sequence with this!

---

### Extra explanation

Usual bottleneck in Application/Script is not CPU, but is *IO*. IO includes writing, reading, waiting, etc. Accessing HDD or sending web request is a very IO-intensive workload which all CPU does is waiting.

To illustrate, IO works are basically like this:

> "Hey OS, please do this IO works for me. Wake me up when it's done."
> Thread 1 goes to sleep
>
> Some time later, OS punches Thread 1
> "Your IO Operation is done, take this and get back to work."

This is why you see in many applications & frameworks uses *Threading* to improve throughput despite the existence of [Global Interpreter Lock(GIL)](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) limiting python code to be ran in only 1 thread at any given time.

GIL is released while waiting for OS's interruption, allowing CPU do something more useful than waiting. Thus CPU can do other thread's work meanwhile.

But thread isn't free: despite much lighter than *Process*, it still generate quite a overhead creating threads.

Asynchronous IO Frameworks' main idea is to benefit from blocking IO works(read, write, wait, etc..) out of synchronous code, but without that Thread overheads.

They use something called [`Awaitables`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=to_thread#awaitables) instead of threads - which is roughly some sort of coroutines like `futures` you previously used.

---

Let me know if there's any error - writing in mobile should've made quite some mistakes I think - double checked though!

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to [jupiterbjy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10909029/jupiterbjy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76162674/51760), if you want your code to "work", you need to wait for the inflight tasks, which you can do using [waiting functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives), or higher level constructs provided by the executor. For instance, [asyncio.event_loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html).

```py
"""Sample script to test asyncio functionality."""

import asyncio
import time


async def wait(i: int) -> None:
    print(f"Task {i} started!")

    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
    except (asyncio.CancelledError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        print(f"Task {i} canceled!")
        raise

    print(f"Task {i} done!")


async def main() -> None:
    """The main."""
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(wait(i)) for i in range(10)]

    print("Blocking main thread for 5 sec!")
    time.sleep(5)
    await asyncio.wait(tasks) # notice this

    print("End of main!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main=main())
    print("asyncio loop stopped!")
```