# asyncio.sleep is behaving like a blocker

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm having a big problem trying to run this the way it's supposed to.
I have a `store` function, which is supposed to simulate writing to a database. Currently I'm writing to a text file instead. To do that, I have a boolean which is used to introduce a delay.

```py
import asyncio
import os
import time

async def store(text, delay: bool = False):
    mode = "a" if os.path.exists(DB_FILE) else "w"
    if delay:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
    with open(DB_FILE, mode=mode) as f:
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        row = f"{text}\t{timestamp}\n"
        f.write(row)
        f.flush()
        print("done saving")
```

I then have a function that simulates writing several changes to that database, and then gets the latest. If there is a delay in the last store function, then it wont count as "latest".

```py
texts = [("how", False), ("are", False), ("you", True)]

async def run_tests():
    initial_text = "hi"
    await store(initial_text)
    curr_text = initial_text
    last_finished = initial_text
    for text, delay in texts:
        await store(text, delay=delay)
        if not delay:  # if finished
            last_finished = curr_text
    assert last_finished == "are"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_tests())
```

I tried running this with both `asyncio.run()` and `loop.run_until_complete()`, but neither is working. `asyncio.sleep` still behaves like `time.sleep`.

Ideally I want the line

```py
await store(text, delay=delay)
```

to execute asynchronously while the rest of the function `run_tests` keeps going.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your example is quite confusing and leaves out several pieces of information like what is `transcription_api` or `ground_truth`. I cannot replicate it because of the lack of said information. Would you provide a more [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You’re right. Sorry, I tried to adapt the one I had to be a bit more clear and represent better the root of the problem. Forgot those lines. It should be ok now

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76110617) answer your question?

Comment: It does a bit, just not so sure how I’d apply them to this example. I want to assert while I wait than the last saved is element 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) that is blocking you here. It is that you `await` each coroutine `store` in your `for`-loop. That means *literally* you wait for it to execute completely before continuing with your iteration.

If you want to schedule each coroutine **immediately**, but not wait for it to **finish**, you can use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) on them. Just make sure to await all the tasks at *some* point.

Here is a simplified example:

```py
from asyncio import create_task, gather, run, sleep


async def store(text: str, delay: bool = False) -> None:
    print(text)
    if delay:
        await sleep(5)


texts = [
    ("hi", False),
    ("how", False),
    ("are", False),
    ("you", True),
]


async def run_tests() -> None:
    last_finished: str | None = None
    tasks = []
    for text, delay in texts:
        tasks.append(create_task(store(text, delay=delay)))
        if not delay:
            last_finished = text
    await gather(*tasks)
    assert last_finished == "are"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(run_tests())
```

I used [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) here for convenience to await all the tasks at the end.

If you are on Python `>=3.11`, you can use a [`asyncio.TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) context manager instead:

```py
from asyncio import TaskGroup, run, sleep

...

async def run_tests() -> None:
    last_finished: str | None = None
    async with TaskGroup() as task_group:
        for text, delay in texts:
            task_group.create_task(store(text, delay=delay))
            if not delay:
                last_finished = text
    assert last_finished == "are"
```

But I have to say the variable naming you use is a bit confusing because `last_finished` suggests that the coroutine that was **scheduled** last (with the `"are"` text) is also the one that is **done** last. That is **not true** in general!

Once a coroutine is scheduled, there are no inherent guarantees that it will finish before or after some other scheduled coroutine, no matter which was scheduled first. To ensure that, you would have to make use of some sort of [synchronization primitive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html).

Depending on the actual context, this may be especially important because you were talking about writing things to a database. But in this super simple example the order is likely to hold true.

Comment: yes! this was it! super clear!!! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want execution to keep going, you can use [create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks), which schedules the task and lets the calling coroutine continue, unlike `await` which pauses the calling coroutine while waiting.